# Hidden input still showing in source code

Tags: php, html

I can't figure out why my hidden input field is still showing in the source code of the page:

```
<form method="POST" ACTION="score.php">
  <ul class="answer">
     <li>
       <input type="checkbox" name="answer_0" value="<?php echo $answer_0; ?>"><?php echo answer_0;?></br>
       <input type="hidden" name="right" value="<?php echo $right;?>"/>
     </li>
  </ul>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What is wrong here ? I tried without the PHP variable and the hidden field was still showing.

Comment: Hiding just prevents it from being rendered, it doesn't change the source.

Comment: if this was an examination question, all the students will know the right answer haha!

Comment: @Barmar is correct. Source code will still show hidden fields. All DOM and rendered HTML codes are being shown here

Comment: well hiding the answer in the exam source is not the brightest idea ever

Comment: Thanks. How can i pass the value of the right answer without showing it in the source code then?

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't, keep the answer in the php code\db

Comment: take the answer back and validate it on the server side

Comment: @sbjumani trying to pass the value of the right answer to score.php

Comment: pass the selected answer and an id representing the question and have code to validate that answer with the answer. None of this should be done on the client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here. Hidden inputs should not be used for data that the user must not be able to see. It's just used for data that they don't *need* to see, and would just clutter up the form.

If you want to hide something from the user securely, you should use session variables. These are kept on the server, not sent to the browser. If you do need to send something to the browser, and don't want the user to be able to get anything from it, you could encrypt it first. But remember, you can't trust that the user won't modify it before sending it back. Anything that comes from the browser can be tweaked by the user.